# create a 3rd map with two map

Tags: apex

```java
for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fieldList) {
    valuemap.put(f.getFieldPath(),f.Label);
}

for(ServiceContract sc : [select Id,Assortment__c,Availability__c ,Internationalization__c,Convenience__c From ServiceContract where Id =:strServiceContractId LIMIT 1]){
    for(String fP: valuemap.values()){
        Object value = sc.get(fP);
        mapObj.put(fP, String.valueOf(value));
    }
}
```

Both the map has same key different values , i need to create a 3rd map with both the value pairs.

Comment: Edward - welcome to SFSE; please see[ask] on getting the most form the Community. Specifically, show us the code you have written so far and where you are stuck - use [edit] as the community approach is to help when good faith effort is made.

Comment: Please do not change the content of your post to a different question. I've rolled back the change. Open a new question if you have a different issue. If this question is solved, consider accepting an answer that provided the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
public static void concatMap(Map<String, Set<String>> targetMap, Map<String, String> sourceMap) {
    for(String key : sourceMap.keySet()) {
        String tempValue = sourceMap.get(key);
        if(targetMap.containsKey(key)) {
            targetMap.get(key).add(tempValue);
        } else {
            targetMap.put(key, new Set<String> { tempValue });
        }
    }
}

Map<String, String> testMap1 = new Map<String, String> {
        'key1' => 'value1_1',
        'key2' => 'value2'
};
Map<String, String> testMap2 = new Map<String, String> {
        'key1' => 'value1_2',
        'key3' => 'value3'
};

Map<String, Set<String>> testMap3 = new Map<String, Set<String>>();
concatMap( testMap3, testMap1);
concatMap( testMap3, testMap2);

System.debug(testMap3);
```

It outputs the following: `{key1={value1_1, value1_2}, key2={value2}, key3={value3}}`

You can use, for example, `List<String>` instead of `Set<String>` if you need to store repeatable values.